# multi-column FKs with NULL values

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, null

I understand that in PostgreSQL if there is a multi-column FK from table `B` to table `A` and one or more of the FK columns in table `B` are nullable then the FK is still considered as "honored" for the rows in `B` where the value of such columns is indeed NULL with no check for the presence of a corresponding row in table `A` (as primary key columns cannot be nullable):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e1c8b)

However, is this PostgreSQL-specific or is it in the SQL standard? (experimenting with SQL Fiddle it seems that both MS SQL Server and MySQL behave in the same way).

Comment: This is the (default) `MATCH SIMPLE` behaviour of foreign keys. Check the related question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/match-full-vs-match-simple

Comment: @ypercube thanks; yet the links in the related question are all in postgresql documentation. My question is whether this is as per the SQL standard or not.

Comment: Yes, it's in the standard. If no one else answers, I'll add an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior (allowing `NULL` values in FK columns) conforms to the SQL standard. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-COMPATIBILITY)

> The `CREATE TABLE` command conforms to the SQL standard, with exceptions listed below.

And there is no exception listed for FK constraints.

To disallow that *some* columns of a multi-column FK are NULL, use `MATCH FULL` instead of the default `MATCH SIMPLE` behavior. [The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

> `MATCH FULL` will not allow one column of a multicolumn foreign key to
>   be null unless all foreign key columns are null; if they are all null,
>   the row is not required to have a match in the referenced table.

Or just define some or all column `NOT NULL`. More here (as @ypercube commented):

- [MATCH FULL vs MATCH SIMPLE in foreign key constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/match-full-vs-match-simple/71508#71508)