# Foreign key refencing multiple primary keys

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, postgresql-9.6

I have multiple tables sharing a common unique ID in my Postgres database.

Parent tables:

```
table1 - id1
table2 - id2
table3 - id3
```

`id1`, `id2`, and `id3` are unique across the database.

Child table:

```
table_child - id  -- referencing id1, id2, id3
```

`id` can have any value from `id1` or `id2` or `id3`.

Is this kind of design possible?

Answer (score 3):

A [`FOREIGN KEY` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) can only ever reference a **single target table** by design.

Maybe [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) or [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) fits your use case?
If not, here are possible workarounds:

#### Without primary table

You need to enforce uniqueness of id values  across `table1` - `table3` some other way. This solution does not take care of it.

We can work with the behavior of default match type **`MATCH SIMPLE`** of `FOREIGN KEY` constraints: If at least one column of an outgoing multicolumn FK constraint is `NULL`, the constraint is not enforced for the row.  See:

- [Differences between MATCH FULL, MATCH SIMPLE, and MATCH PARTIAL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/differences-between-match-full-match-simple-and-match-partial/71508#71508)

This way we can switch FK constraints on and off on demand:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id1  integer
, t1   bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true CHECK (t1)
, col1 text
, CONSTRAINT t1_uni_for_mixed_fk UNIQUE (id1, t1)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id2  integer PRIMARY KEY
, t2   bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true CHECK (t2)
, col2 text
, CONSTRAINT t2_uni_for_mixed_fk UNIQUE (id2, t2)
);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id3  integer PRIMARY KEY
, t3   bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true CHECK (t3)
, col3 text
, CONSTRAINT t3_uni_for_mixed_fk UNIQUE (id3, t3)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, mix_id integer NOT NULL
, t1 bool
, t2 bool
, t3 bool  
, CONSTRAINT max_one_source CHECK (num_nonnulls(t1, t2, t3) < 2)
-- , CONSTRAINT exactly_one_source CHECK num_nonnulls(t1, t2, t3) = 1  -- or this?
, CONSTRAINT child_mix_id1_fk FOREIGN KEY (mix_id, t1) REFERENCES table1 (id1, t1)
, CONSTRAINT child_mix_id2_fk FOREIGN KEY (mix_id, t2) REFERENCES table2 (id2, t2)
, CONSTRAINT child_mix_id3_fk FOREIGN KEY (mix_id, t3) REFERENCES table3 (id3, t3)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fc7dcb8eeb273bf2e6d3fdda6f5a11e6)*

The `CHECK` constraint `max_one_source` enforces at most one FK.
The alternative `CHECK` constraint `exactly_one_source` enforces exactly one FK.
The columns `tabl1.t1` etc. are logically redundant but required for the multicolumn FK constraint. (Unfortunately, we cannot just use a constant in the FK definition.) I made each default to `true` and accept no other value.

The `UNIQUE` constraints `t1_uni_for_mixed_fk` etc. include the logically redundant `t1` etc. Required for the FK constraint. (Can replace a simple PK on just `id1` etc.

#### With primary table

To enforce your model, create a central table holding a central `PRIMARY KEY`. This way, uniqueness of `id` across `table1` - `table3` is also enforced reliably.

```
CREATE TABLE central (
  central_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, kind "char" CHECK (kind IN ('1', '2', '3'))
, CONSTRAINT unique_for_fk UNIQUE (central_id, kind)
);

CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id1 integer PRIMARY KEY
, kind "char" NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' CHECK (kind = '1')
, col1 text   
  -- more ...
, CONSTRAINT table1_id1_central_fk FOREIGN KEY (id1, kind) REFERENCES central (central_id, kind)
);

-- CREATE TABLE table2 ... ;
-- CREATE TABLE table3 ... ;

CREATE TABLE child (
  child_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, central_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES central
  -- more ...   
);
```

Inserts into `table_a` etc. could look like this:

```
-- generate ID of kind "a" in a CTE
WITH cte AS (INSERT INTO central(kind) VALUES ('1') RETURNING central_id)
INSERT INTO table1 (id1, col1)
SELECT central_id, 'col1_value'
FROM   cte;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6e0d496a61950044215846263a0b7c7d)*

Each ID can only be of one kind, and any "child" table has single point of reference.

Column `kind` is logically redundant in `table_a` etc., but required for the FK constraint. I made it so that nothing but the right value can be entered.

The `UNIQUE` constraint `unique_for_fk` is also logically redundant. Required for the FK constraint.

Related:

- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)