# Foreign Key - from same table and parent table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I have 2 tables.

First table is parent

**COLLECTIONS_OF_MAPS**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 50013 | Geological Map Series |
| 50014 | Climate Map Series |

Second table is a child (but whilst describing map layers, it also has entries that are more like group layers, like parents to child maps within the same table, so there is a recursion element here) - this is then realised in a treeview control in software, just for context purposes.

**MAP_LAYERS**

| id | parent_layer_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | 50013 | Hillshade |
| 1228 | 50013 | Cultural Data |
| 1231 | 50013 | Rock Types |
| 1235 | 1233 | Offshore Hillshade |
| 1234 | 1233 | Onshore Hillshade |
| 1229 | 1228 | World Cities |
| 1230 | 1228 | World Countries |
| 1245 | 1228 | World Rivers |
| 1270 | 1231 | Sedimentary Rock |
| 1271 | 1231 | Igneous Rock |
| 1272 | 1231 | Metamorphic Rock |

I have just shown an example for the first map collection - "Geological Map Series".

As you can see it the MAP_LAYERS parent_layer_id column references entries from BOTH tables; it's parent and itself.
Can I create a foreign key rule to that references the ids of itself and or its parent table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** A [foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraint can only have a single target table.
[Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) is no workaround. The manual:

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
> (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
> to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on
> both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

You could build a less strict replacement with triggers. Or with a `NOT VALID` check constraint using a fake `IMMUTABLE` function to check on `INSERT` only. See:

- [How to avoid a cyclic dependency (circular reference) between 3 tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123987/how-to-avoid-a-cyclic-dependency-circular-reference-between-3-tables/124019#124019)

Neither enforces strict referential integrity. If you need that, you have to modify your table definition.

#### Split column

Ideally, a column should contain *one* kind of data to begin with. So this is the cleanest way:

```
CREATE TABLE collections_of_maps (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, title text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE map_layers (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, parent_collection_id int
, parent_layer_id int
, name text NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_one_parent_chk CHECK (num_nulls(parent_collection_id, parent_layer_id) = 1)
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_parent_collection_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_collection_id) REFERENCES collections_of_maps
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_parent_layer_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_layer_id) REFERENCES map_layers
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=62f439dd9c4181c85c570a7bdff09227)*

About `num_nulls()`:

- [Count NULL values per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205887/count-null-values-per-row/205899#205899)

#### Keep single column

If you must keep a single `parent_id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE collections_of_maps (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
, parent_collection bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true CHECK (parent_collection)   -- ! ③
, title text NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT collections_of_maps_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, parent_collection)  -- ! ③
);

CREATE TABLE map_layers (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, parent_id int NOT NULL                            -- !
, parent_collection bool CHECK (parent_collection)  -- ! ①
, parent_layer bool CHECK (parent_layer)            -- !
, name text NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_one_parent CHECK (num_nulls(parent_collection, parent_layer) = 1)  -- ! ②
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_for_fk_uni UNIQUE (id, parent_collection)  -- !
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_parent_collection_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, parent_collection) REFERENCES collections_of_maps (id, parent_collection)
, CONSTRAINT map_layers_parent_layer_id_fk      FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, parent_layer)      REFERENCES map_layers          (id, parent_collection)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=734051d62f06129e713b7c7fcb580c16)*

I added two boolean flags `parent_collection` and `parent_layer` to mark the type of parent. CHECK constraints enforce that one of both flags must be `null`, and the other one `true`.

① Simple `CHECK` enforces `true` (or `null`).
② Enforces exactly one of both `null`.

Related:

- [Constraint - one boolean row is true, all other rows false](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197562/constraint-one-boolean-row-is-true-all-other-rows-false/197575#197575)

The default `MATCH SIMPLE` behavior of multicolumn FK constraints does not enforce the FK if one of the columns is NULL. See:

- [Differences between MATCH FULL, MATCH SIMPLE, and MATCH PARTIAL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/differences-between-match-full-match-simple-and-match-partial/71508#71508)

Thus, only the right one of the two FK constraints is enforced for each row.

③ We need to add the logically redundant flag `parent_collection` and include it in a UNIQUE or PK constraint to allow the multicolumn FK reference. I appropriated the PK for the purpose. Alternatively (if you need the plain PK) add a (redundant) `UNIQUE` constraint.

The way I implemented it, self-references cannot be nested. I.e., rows in `map_layers` can only reference rows in `map_layers` that reference `collections_of_maps`. See example in the fiddle. Can be adapted ...

Comment: Thanks for your time in putting together such a comprehensive answer. I think ultimately my table design is wrong, so I may have to change it so I have proper referential integrity.

Comment: Is the NumNulls just checking there can only be one out of the two columns with a NULL value?

Comment: @Vidar: `numnulls()` simply counts the number of NULL values in the input. It's a `VARIADIC` function taking up to 100 arguments. It's all in the linked answer.